# The commutator of a Lie algebra element with a Lie group element

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there a way to evaluate the trace of generators of the Lie algebra and group elements?

For example take $SO(N)$, with $\lbrace T^a\rbrace$ the set of generators, normalized such that $Tr(T^aT^b)=\delta^{ab}$ and $g= e^{i \theta^aT^a}$ is a group element of the Lie group.

Is there a way to compute the commutator of a Lie-algebra element with a Lie group element generated by the generators in the same representation? Something like $[T^a,g]=?$

( In fact I was wondering if there was a simple relation between the elements of the adjoint representation. If you compute the matrix of the action of $g$ on $T^b$ projected onto $T^a$ how is related to the projection of that same action g on  $T^a$ projected onto $T^b$.)

Comment: Whenever you select a basis for a Lie algebra, you can find the associated [structure constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants), which completely determine $[\cdot,\cdot]$ over the algebra.  Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to diagonalise your $g$ matrix first and then evaluate $T^a$ in this basis. Then the computation is quite easy.